# Printer's head keeps getting dirty

Tags: printer, cleaning

My printer's head keeps getting very dirty after printing a few pages. I noticed that the little sponge (I don't know how to better call it), placed on the right side of the printer where the head rests, is saturated with ink. I believe it could be the problem and I was wondering if someone has some suggestions on how to clean or replace that component.

My printer is a Canon Pixma Pro 9000 Mark II

Comment: Have a look at https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2946613 - you may or may not be able to wash the pads, but I put to you that (a) this is a very old printer, and unless there are exceptional circumstances its probably not worth the effort and (b) replacing it with a low-end laser printer will probably be cheaper in the long run due to wasted ink costs.

Comment: Well, a laser would not work for artistic prints... So far I partly resolved by manually absorbing the ink in excess using some absorbing paper. I don't think it's going to fix the problem in the long term though.